# Matplotlib align x-axes on subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot, imshow

I am trying to put together a plot that incorporates multiple different data frames that share a common index. Despite setting all the X-axes to the same labels and ticks they still don't lineup within the as be seen with the top x-axis. Causing whitespace on the right y-axis.
[Output Graph Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRouU.png)

```
fig,axe=plt.subplots()
axe.set_xlabel('Total Collectors in Array')
axe.set_ylabel('Energy Generated (MJ)')
plt.xticks(ticks=df.index.values,labels=df.index.values) 
axe.plot(df,label= label_list,zorder=0,marker='o')

labelLines(axe.get_lines())

ax3=axe.twiny()
ax2=axe.twinx()

ax3.plot(df3,label=label_list,zorder=1,linewidth=1,linestyle='--')
ax3.axes.xaxis.set_visible(True)
labelLines(ax3.get_lines(),align=False,xvals=[1.5]*10,zorder=2.5)

ax2.set_ylabel('DHW Draw Rate')
ax2.imshow(df2,zorder=2,
    cmap='CMRmap',alpha=0.3,origin='lower')
a=ax2.get_xticks().tolist()
label_list1=label_list[:]
ax2.set(xticks=x_lab,xticklabels=x_lab,yticks=y_ticks,yticklabels=label_list1)


fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to specify the extent of the imshow.